# LinkedIn Article Post API giving 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: api, linkedin-api, reset

I'm trying to post an article on LinkedIn via their new Post API.

Below is my curl request. Which follows their documentation.

Problem: Randomly Article Post giving 500 Internal Server Error from LinkedIn

The image is uploaded via the Image API and urn works in an "image" post.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer UserAccessToken' \
--header 'X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0' \
--header 'LinkedIn-Version: 202208' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "author": "urn:li:person:ownerid1234",
    "commentary": "UnitTest ArticlePost with Latest API",
    "visibility": "PUBLIC",
    "distribution": {
        "feedDistribution": "MAIN_FEED",
        "targetEntities": [],
        "thirdPartyDistributionChannels": []
    },
    "content": {
        "article": {
            "source": "https://shorturl.at/cfhL4",
            "title": "Article Post",
            "description": "",
            "thumbnail": "urn:li:image:C5610AQE5yn7MbvKXow"
        }
    },
    "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
    "isReshareDisabledByAuthor": false
}'
```